# Fastest way to replace multiple elements in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Simple example for replacing values in the array according to a list:

```
import numpy as np

l = [1,3,4,15]
a = np.array([1,1,2,4,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,89,12,23,3,4,10,15])
for element in l:
     a = np.where(a == element, 0, a)
```

Since this is rather slow, I'm looking for a faster alternative, that scales well.

Comment: The dupe is not quite right. `np.where` is precisely what is needed here (no looping needed)

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`np.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html):

```
np.where(np.in1d(a, l), 0, a)

array([ 0,  0,  2,  0,  6,  7,  8,  9,  0,  2,  0,  0, 89, 12, 23,  0,  0,
       10,  0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `numpy.where` with `numpy.isin`:

```
np.where(np.isin(a, l), 0, a)
```

Output:

```
array([ 0,  0,  2,  0,  6,  7,  8,  9,  0,  2,  0,  0, 89, 12, 23,  0,  0,
       10,  0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`np.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html):

```
a = np.where(np.isin(a, l), 0, a)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[ 0  0  2  0  6  7  8  9  0  2  0  0 89 12 23  0  0 10  0]
```

If your version of numpy is small than 1.13.0, use @yatu's answer.

Since as mentioned in the [documentation's](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) notes:

> *New in version 1.13.0.*